# In Seaborn: ValueError: Image size of 2583019x1677798 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Image size of 2583019x1677798 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
```

when trying to plot a series with seaborn.

What would be the easiest way to overcome it?

For a reproducible example:

```
toy_data.to_json()

{"Gold":{"1503878400000":0.172271396,"1503964800000":0.3648271902,"1504051200000":0.3495217227,"1504137600000":0.3842178158,"1504224000000":0.6273921273,"1504483200000":0.7471582138,"1504569600000":0.7881750342,"1504656000000":0.8201462095,"1504742400000":0.8031194038,"1504828800000":0.7948675789,"1505088000000":0.6903873543,"1505174400000":0.5125170013,"1505260800000":0.2907401668,"1505347200000":0.0001655103,"1505433600000":0.2591904543,"1505692800000":0.5086684503,"1505779200000":0.8090657709,"1505865600000":0.8371236075,"1505952000000":0.8843171231,"1506038400000":0.8921443976,"1506297600000":0.8843858967,"1506384000000":0.7595621096,"1506470400000":0.7441755853,"1506556800000":0.7598001132,"1506643200000":0.7235960537,"1506902400000":0.7413946633,"1506988800000":0.7892794431,"1507075200000":0.738047252,"1507161600000":0.7083847981,"1507248000000":0.7467286537,"1507507200000":0.5179591997,"1507593600000":0.0551439144,"1507680000000":0.0677893113,"1507766400000":0.3451610907,"1507852800000":0.781481841,"1508112000000":0.850074365,"1508198400000":0.6742261872,"1508284800000":0.293432449,"1508371200000":0.1006276785,"1508457600000":0.069278445,"1508716800000":0.4274518025,"1508803200000":0.5861627165,"1508889600000":0.7481119031,"1508976000000":0.6890294775,"1509062400000":0.72248124,"1509321600000":0.7352849813,"1509408000000":0.5697190724,"1509494400000":0.2290622016,"1509580800000":0.0331331972,"1509667200000":0.0047112157,"1509926400000":0.0071132881,"1510012800000":0.0447725004,"1510099200000":0.1710056573,"1510185600000":0.554831659,"1510272000000":0.5372760467,"1510531200000":0.3432156276,"1510617600000":0.0501417938,"1510704000000":0.2414606059,"1510790400000":0.1293155883,"1510876800000":0.1382437514,"1511136000000":0.1713896739,"1511222400000":0.0258907969,"1511308800000":0.0462335267,"1511395200000":0.2247792982,"1511481600000":0.4418558182,"1511740800000":0.5246211873,"1511827200000":0.464418999,"1511913600000":0.6224438438,"1512000000000":0.1143829725,"1512086400000":0.019505194,"1512345600000":0.0446810287,"1512432000000":0.3752794783,"1512518400000":0.7215269372,"1512604800000":0.8237731127,"1512691200000":0.907650383,"1512950400000":0.9250455984,"1513036800000":0.932924066,"1513123200000":0.9230832053,"1513209600000":0.7407633061,"1513296000000":0.5029020712,"1513555200000":0.1966170028,"1513641600000":0.004505177,"1513728000000":0.433811201,"1513814400000":0.7760605998,"1513900800000":0.8002226045,"1514160000000":0.8659655593,"1514246400000":0.7884844635,"1514332800000":0.7854856997,"1514419200000":0.7861962433,"1514505600000":0.8213732109,"1514764800000":0.8495962631,"1514851200000":0.8835000755,"1514937600000":0.9332227527,"1515024000000":0.9394060293,"1515110400000":0.9306571246,"1515369600000":0.8925219401,"1515456000000":0.8373869506,"1515542400000":0.8002284916,"1515628800000":0.7105925053,"1515715200000":0.7103015093,"1515974400000":0.692322274,"1516060800000":0.7392157471,"1516147200000":0.7808519631,"1516233600000":0.6145028968,"1516320000000":0.5760125484,"1516579200000":0.4591408771,"1516665600000":0.3083468935,"1516752000000":0.3457387662,"1516838400000":0.3653983232,"1516924800000":0.4478057871,"1517184000000":0.6206162757,"1517270400000":0.5180292166,"1517356800000":0.3748451788,"1517443200000":0.095946808,"1517529600000":0.0089392313,"1517788800000":0.1791601355,"1517875200000":0.616619233,"1517961600000":0.7606160481,"1518048000000":0.6784372777,"1518134400000":0.7107504735,"1518393600000":0.7040624757,"1518480000000":0.5480084294,"1518566400000":0.3588284763,"1518652800000":0.0061525806,"1518739200000":0.1508845761,"1518998400000":0.3232824094,"1519084800000":0.5612998708,"1519171200000":0.403494816,"1519257600000":0.0734070214,"1519344000000":0.0045505675,"1519603200000":0.0749623126,"1519689600000":0.2437621017,"1519776000000":0.6310234749,"1519862400000":0.6548325869,"1519948800000":0.592646653,"1520208000000":0.3299398417,"1520294400000":0.1538456318,"1520380800000":0.0226683814,"1520467200000":0.0432992505,"1520553600000":0.0663242788,"1520812800000":0.0060548174,"1520899200000":0.0189552314,"1520985600000":0.0408943988,"1521072000000":0.0151918656,"1521158400000":0.2624258819,"1521417600000":0.4097845096,"1521504000000":0.524245162,"1521590400000":0.3561681038,"1521676800000":0.000488645,"1521763200000":0.1894809999,"1522022400000":0.3761750834,"1522108800000":0.5341671953,"1522195200000":0.6563073997,"1522281600000":0.441838353,"1522368000000":0.2295861072,"1522627200000":0.0300418173,"1522713600000":0.001862048,"1522800000000":0.0536877421,"1522886400000":0.2644677682,"1522972800000":0.2994607839,"1523232000000":0.1750264727,"1523318400000":0.0006975425,"1523404800000":0.3124262309,"1523491200000":0.3787442789,"1523577600000":0.3107183738,"1523836800000":0.2499888947,"1523923200000":0.3435659305,"1524009600000":0.740153936,"1524096000000":0.6918559082,"1524182400000":0.3517574297,"1524441600000":0.0611545984,"1524528000000":0.4657889114,"1524614400000":0.6044948001,"1524700800000":0.6946191315,"1524787200000":0.8526492125,"1525046400000":0.8993210271,"1525132800000":0.9437954308,"1525219200000":0.9208095274,"1525305600000":0.8760768828,"1525392000000":0.891787079,"1525651200000":0.8499836725,"1525737600000":0.7547580746,"1525824000000":0.7300416761,"1525910400000":0.2455091438,"1525996800000":0.0941730179,"1526256000000":0.4222054924,"1526342400000":0.1937917585,"1526428800000":0.027806913,"1526515200000":0.1760093648,"1526601600000":0.383626096,"1526860800000":0.5642462079,"1526947200000":0.6015747265,"1527033600000":0.6453304329,"1527120000000":0.5011413307,"1527206400000":0.1336998125,"1527465600000":0.0485807216,"1527552000000":0.7339607699,"1527638400000":0.7372317789,"1527724800000":0.7361141514,"1527811200000":0.516832331,"1528070400000":0.071475867,"1528156800000":0.0551769782,"1528243200000":0.3724208691,"1528329600000":0.6024099822,"1528416000000":0.3520402813,"1528675200000":0.23232879,"1528761600000":0.0575912234,"1528848000000":0.1047867963,"1528934400000":0.1922281356,"1529020800000":0.4319829014,"1529280000000":0.015038107,"1529366400000":0.2763157034,"1529452800000":0.5306137095,"1529539200000":0.683154767,"1529625600000":0.7471560924,"1529884800000":0.790161397,"1529971200000":0.8332844847,"1530057600000":0.8610592577,"1530144000000":0.8601097457,"1530230400000":0.900588943,"1530489600000":0.8852063346,"1530576000000":0.87322315,"1530662400000":0.605539783,"1530748800000":0.5289132009,"1530835200000":0.2726446115,"1531094400000":0.0450905762,"1531180800000":0.1395115401,"1531267200000":0.1742297955,"1531353600000":0.0023064719,"1531440000000":0.0923363766,"1531699200000":0.2537566849,"1531785600000":0.6318503388,"1531872000000":0.667650013,"1531958400000":0.802331854,"1532044800000":0.8535289076,"1532304000000":0.7380762098,"1532390400000":0.6761082313,"1532476800000":0.4683005291,"1532563200000":0.3081242025,"1532649600000":0.3040215747,"1532908800000":0.152184619,"1532995200000":0.0158750092,"1533081600000":0.0342820083,"1533168000000":0.4867677703,"1533254400000":0.6854868697,"1533513600000":0.7018600142,"1533600000000":0.7060491884,"1533686400000":0.6241319345,"1533772800000":0.392550799,"1533859200000":0.4332673817,"1534118400000":0.4767332717,"1534204800000":0.5646474352,"1534291200000":0.5821807226,"1534377600000":0.6563882586,"1534464000000":0.8522480746,"1534723200000":0.8376389146,"1534809600000":0.6448541282,"1534896000000":0.3847216524,"1534982400000":0.223064124,"1535068800000":0.0320857359,"1535328000000":0.0501433933,"1535414400000":0.4721604449,"1535500800000":0.6132403591,"1535587200000":0.5554380848,"1535673600000":0.4864325365,"1535932800000":0.3787078908,"1536019200000":0.2061410178,"1536105600000":0.1037590312,"1536192000000":0.0331213697,"1536278400000":0.0095958532,"1536537600000":0.4738173662,"1536624000000":0.4143481061,"1536710400000":0.3185711867,"1536796800000":0.0202308695,"1536883200000":0.1350824006,"1537142400000":0.1188727305,"1537228800000":0.0437326517,"1537315200000":0.014649155,"1537401600000":0.1589711922,"1537488000000":0.3758255493,"1537747200000":0.1157946234,"1537833600000":0.0027210759,"1537920000000":0.1581969215,"1538006400000":0.1636412654,"1538092800000":0.2856608159,"1538352000000":0.6118188464,"1538438400000":0.6794095002,"1538524800000":0.2659411203,"1538611200000":0.0960837669,"1538697600000":0.009957789,"1538956800000":0.0266140636,"1539043200000":0.0064889931,"1539129600000":0.0006276277,"1539216000000":0.0794091794,"1539302400000":0.1776513421,"1539561600000":0.2985894365,"1539648000000":0.4153693264,"1539734400000":0.6007958527,"1539820800000":0.6659724917,"1539907200000":0.7297424195,"1540166400000":0.6162303127,"1540252800000":0.5422571796,"1540339200000":0.4019121725,"1540425600000":0.2388132246,"1540512000000":0.1787345158,"1540771200000":0.3642012863,"1540857600000":0.0240490162,"1540944000000":0.0510141725,"1541030400000":0.2000499101,"1541116800000":0.0500869876,"1541376000000":0.1073150165,"1541462400000":0.000052062,"1541548800000":0.0395551505,"1541635200000":0.0137335779,"1541721600000":0.0087933446,"1541980800000":0.041512976,"1542067200000":0.3342933585,"1542153600000":0.6772989038,"1542240000000":0.7886083747,"1542326400000":0.5921085559,"1542585600000":0.2672003983,"1542672000000":0.0298696791,"1542758400000":0.1115931642,"1542844800000":0.4949768908,"1542931200000":0.7717585107,"1543190400000":0.7878320268,"1543276800000":0.6631143708,"1543363200000":0.1052891607,"1543449600000":0.0179693254,"1543536000000":0.0761293295,"1543795200000":0.0012039656,"1543881600000":0.1332859189,"1543968000000":0.2662881331,"1544054400000":0.5005958554,"1544140800000":0.5972307619,"1544400000000":0.781030799,"1544486400000":0.8789991552,"1544572800000":0.8225209939,"1544659200000":0.7383078158,"1544745600000":0.4333299121,"1545004800000":0.0954447958,"1545091200000":0.1872969812,"1545177600000":0.1543438309,"1545264000000":0.1883924027,"1545350400000":0.2968447713,"1545609600000":0.5442124584,"1545696000000":0.7870513682,"1545782400000":0.8668998609,"1545868800000":0.9371701774,"1545955200000":0.9320034843,"1546214400000":0.9310689903,"1546300800000":0.9426322138,"1546387200000":0.9430773399,"1546473600000":0.9463146277,"1546560000000":0.9411743893,"1546819200000":0.9239022259,"1546905600000":0.7271694234,"1546992000000":0.3993692728,"1547078400000":0.3334871606,"1547164800000":0.2843495803,"1547424000000":0.2844719771,"1547510400000":0.1075154271,"1547596800000":0.0885154616,"1547683200000":0.1565571878,"1547769600000":0.0426239246,"1548028800000":0.0062289428,"1548115200000":0.1161883703,"1548201600000":0.570032873,"1548288000000":0.6598829528,"1548374400000":0.598408179,"1548633600000":0.0013644198,"1548720000000":0.1506546198,"1548806400000":0.4253596632,"1548892800000":0.7555175367,"1548979200000":0.8711627176,"1549238400000":0.7883400157,"1549324800000":0.726791578,"1549411200000":0.5974750286,"1549497600000":0.2741711386,"1549584000000":0.0174188296,"1549843200000":0.1851887919,"1549929600000":0.4280283855,"1550016000000":0.5106413988,"1550102400000":0.4536187258,"1550188800000":0.000411518,"1550448000000":0.1603469399,"1550534400000":0.48396692,"1550620800000":0.6946347084,"1550707200000":0.7449058751,"1550793600000":0.6099721698,"1551052800000":0.5023968523,"1551139200000":0.3702840923,"1551225600000":0.1869784764,"1551312000000":0.00082258,"1551398400000":0.2874271885,"1551657600000":0.6092816683,"1551744000000":0.7899691655,"1551830400000":0.7944214188,"1551916800000":0.7969727959,"1552003200000":0.7754283134,"1552262400000":0.61762446,"1552348800000":0.4042970184,"1552435200000":0.0562011382,"1552521600000":0.0909263436,"1552608000000":0.7770344245,"1552867200000":0.8195139465,"1552953600000":0.8106744081,"1553040000000":0.6460931111,"1553126400000":0.6445128659,"1553212800000":0.5958829944,"1553472000000":0.6286884393,"1553558400000":0.5663653307,"1553644800000":0.7805890852,"1553731200000":0.3482491765,"1553817600000":0.0159651766,"1554076800000":0.2247810968,"1554163200000":0.4628886458,"1554249600000":0.7536905666,"1554336000000":0.7369689579,"1554422400000":0.7733003517,"1554681600000":0.5286240843,"1554768000000":0.1784897318,"1554854400000":0.0529238342,"1554940800000":0.7006027335,"1555027200000":0.5753485145,"1555286400000":0.1458478939,"1555372800000":0.0124102577,"1555459200000":0.2240819971,"1555545600000":0.4841132049,"1555632000000":0.7996912566,"1555891200000":0.8754888196,"1555977600000":0.8616653817,"1556064000000":0.783167877,"1556150400000":0.6185604916,"1556236800000":0.2127218461,"1556496000000":0.0098642855,"1556582400000":0.5301515093,"1556668800000":0.5980550378,"1556755200000":0.1042054489,"1556841600000":0.0011501302,"1557100800000":0.0763417489,"1557187200000":0.0664285352,"1557273600000":0.0067731297,"1557360000000":0.000354157,"1557446400000":0.0483603361,"1557705600000":0.1284535648,"1557792000000":0.535868611,"1557878400000":0.8247021493,"1557964800000":0.8094348525,"1558051200000":0.5038200324,"1558310400000":0.011330007,"1558396800000":0.0789137957,"1558483200000":0.2173548547,"1558569600000":0.4050776093,"1558656000000":0.4549463977,"1558915200000":0.5612565338,"1559001600000":0.2966403544,"1559088000000":0.0412238733,"1559174400000":0.031026227,"1559260800000":0.5304685308,"1559520000000":0.5805503056,"1559606400000":0.6924654674,"1559692800000":0.760283923,"1559779200000":0.825053611,"1559865600000":0.8668528704,"1560124800000":0.8147264302,"1560211200000":0.6592660192,"1560297600000":0.5719563608,"1560384000000":0.442327618,"1560470400000":0.4307067027,"1560729600000":0.1644951541,"1560816000000":0.1369718373,"1560902400000":0.2682981213,"1560988800000":0.5064416783,"1561075200000":0.6825801718,"1561334400000":0.766317068,"1561420800000":0.7913296261,"1561507200000":0.8185781758,"1561593600000":0.7611584011,"1561680000000":0.7723918241,"1561939200000":0.4994688755,"1562025600000":0.2305828979,"1562112000000":0.1161539675,"1562198400000":0.0422565883,"1562284800000":0.0009818768,"1562544000000":0.0087400765,"1562630400000":0.0031992484,"1562716800000":0.0259327418,"1562803200000":0.002733133,"1562889600000":0.0219924986,"1563148800000":0.0028395266,"1563235200000":0.0074623103,"1563321600000":0.0010467676,"1563408000000":0.1179966537,"1563494400000":0.4542222101,"1563753600000":0.5264327022,"1563840000000":0.2973455977,"1563926400000":0.1687597471,"1564012800000":0.3687714661,"1564099200000":0.1400055072}}'
sns.lineplot(data = toy_data)
    sns.lineplot(data = toy_data)
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x18a4a1231d0>

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
        339                 pass
        340             else:
    --> 341                 return printer(obj)
        342             # Finally look for special method names
        343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
        239 
        240     if 'png' in formats:
    --> 241         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
        242     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
        243         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
        123 
        124     bytes_io = BytesIO()
    --> 125     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
        126     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
        127     if fmt == 'svg':

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
       2261                 orientation=orientation,
       2262                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
    -> 2263                 **kwargs)
       2264         finally:
       2265             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
        511 
        512     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
    --> 513         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
        514         renderer = self.get_renderer()
        515         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
        423         Draw the figure using the renderer
        424         """
    --> 425         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
        426         # acquire a lock on the shared font cache
        427         RendererAgg.lock.acquire()

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in get_renderer(self, cleared)
        448 
        449         if need_new_renderer:
    --> 450             self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
        451             self._lastKey = key
        452         elif cleared:

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in __init__(self, width, height, dpi)
         95         self.width = width
         96         self.height = height
    ---> 97         self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi)
         98         self._filter_renderers = []
         99 

    ValueError: Image size of 2583019x1677798 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

    <Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Comment: The example is not reproducible. `pandas.read_json()` fails with the string provided.

Comment: Please check again.

Comment: I don't know how to get that data in (And I will not type it up.) So can you make sure to provide a runnable code that produces the error you want to get help with? ([mcve])

Comment: I apologize for any inconvenience.  I have replaced the data and I have checked that they are read and return a pandas dataframe with pd.read_json().  Could you please give it another try?

Comment: So [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnBT1.png) how it looks for me in jupyter notebook. Any more details about which versions of libraries you are using, how exactly you run the code, etc?